# How to change Product Version or File Version in IsCmdBld.exe?

Tags: installshield

I'm using InstallShield 2015 Premier.
I made the project(.ism) that is InstallScript type.
I want to change version shown in setup.exe property dialog box.
-z, -y option do not works on my project type.

ex) IsCmdBld.exe -p "C:\projec.ism" -y "2.3.3"      or
IsCmdBld.exe -p "C:\projec.ism" -z "Product_Version=1.2.3"

How can I change version by using IsCmdBld.exe?

Comment: Can you try four digit version scheme?  e.g. IsCmdBld.exe -p "C:\projec.ism" -y "2.3.3.0". See if this works or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It does not works too. But it works on other types of projects(basic MSI, InstallScript MSI). Is there a way to change the version of the InstallScript type? @NileshShinde

Answer (score 1):

For the InstallScript type, you can try this method:

Define a new PATH Variable, say "VERSION_NUMBER", give it some arbitrary version i.e. 1.0.0.0.  In your General Information tab, the Product Version will be defined as .  This will default your version to 1.0.0.0

Then, when you build your InstallScript project with IsCmdBld, add the parameter:
-l VERSION_NUMBER=""